# Does web worker block on the main thread for some OffscreenCanvas functions?

Tags: web-worker

I have a web worker processing an array of saved `ImageData` frames and am using an `OffscreenCanvas`'s context (created in the web worker) to `putImageData`. Meanwhile in my main thread I block on another operation. If I include the `context.putImageData()` call, the web worker blocks until my main thread completes before continuing, but if I remove the `putImageData` call or use `context.clearRect()` the web worker will run concurrently with my main thread.

Even if I'm running in a web worker, is it possible that the web worker blocks on some uses of `OffscreenCanvas`? This also happens with `convertToBlob`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It shouldn't.

But there is indeed a regression caused by [this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1019288), which affects Chrome > 82.

I did open [a bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1076349), so now all we can do is to wait for them to fix it.

Here is the MCVE I produced:

```js
const worker_script = `
postMessage('ready'); // main will block
const now = performance.now();
const off = new OffscreenCanvas(300, 150);
const off_ctx = off.getContext('2d');
off_ctx.fillRect(0,0,30,30)
postMessage( performance.now() - now );
`;
const worker_url = URL.createObjectURL( new Blob( [ worker_script ], { type: "text/javascript" } ) );
const worker = new Worker( worker_url );

worker.onmessage = evt => {
  if (evt.data === "ready" ) {
    blockMainThread( 3000 )
      .then( () => log( 'now free' ) );
  }
  else log( `worker script took ${evt.data}ms to complete.` );
};

worker.postMessage( "" );

function blockMainThread( duration ) {
  return new Promise( ( resolve ) => {
    const now = performance.now();
    while( performance.now() - now < duration ) {}
    resolve();
  } );
}
function log( content ) {
  _log.textContent += content + '\n';
}
```

```html
<pre id="_log">
The page will be frozen for 3s. Please wait.
</pre>
```

Given the nature of that bug, I doubt there is any way to workaround it.