# Webworker Long Network Transfer Time

Tags: javascript, angular, electron, chromium, web-worker

I am using web workers to render images in an off-screen canvas, within an **angular** framework for an **electron** desktop application. Here is roughly what I'm doing within my angular component:

```
@ViewChild('imageCanvas') private m_cImageCanvas!: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>;

setup() {

    // Transfer to offscreen control
    this.m_OffscreenCanvas = this.m_cImageCanvas.nativeElement.transferControlToOffscreen();

    // Create web worker
    this.m_cWebWorker = new Worker('./image-renderer.worker', { type: 'module', name: 'image-renderer-'+this.nId+'.worker' });

    // not shown -setting up worker callbacks .onmessage() and .onerror().

    // Send canvas to web worker
    this.m_cWebWorker.postMessage(
            new ImageWorkerMessageInit(this.nId, this.m_cOffscreenCanvas),
            [this.m_cOffscreenCanvas]
        );
}
```

Note `ImageWorkerMessageInit` is just a simple object that holds the Id, Canvas, and a message code for the web worker. Later in the code I send the worker an image to render.

I was noticing that it took a very long time to actually render images, so I ran the chrome profiler:
[image: Chrome performance analysis of web worker]
As you can see, the Main thread does some tiny amount of processing (~10ms) and then sets up the worker using the `setup()` code above. The Network panel shows a Network Request to the worker of 10.71s, 10.7 of which is for "network transfer". I have verified that this network request begins when I call `new Worker(...)`, and that the worker thread is not able to start work until the transfer is complete. The inspector says the webworker is ~41kB, which cannot possible justify 10s of transfer time.

Any clue what I am missing here? I've spent quite a few hours on google and stack overflow trying to find causes of a large network transfer time for spawning new workers but didn't find anything particularly relevant. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Not very used to that graph, but does it mean you have 16 Workers launched at the same time? Also, in Chrome Workers will block on the main thread waiting for an access to the GPU. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61475472/does-web-worker-block-on-the-main-thread-for-some-offscreencanvas-functions/61497076#61497076 but that's weird here because your main thread seems to idle quite often...

Comment: Yes each of those rows is a separate worker, but they don't necessarily exist concurrently (each worker is terminated after its job is complete, but the row remains to show CPU usage, etc.). Thank you for the pointer to the GPU-blocking issue, I wasn't aware of that bug. I agree that it does not seem to be the root cause here, the GPU and Main thread activity seem fairly low.